# Linear mixed model dependent variable transformation - is this appropriate

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, data-transformation, residuals

I have basically measured a skin conductance over an experiment. Now my dependent variable is the skin conductance at the time of an event. There are several events (scenario) during the experiment.
I fit the model: lmer(skin_conductance_per_min ~ scenario + (1 | id), data = mydata). When inspecting the residuals of my model I notice that they follow a shape of a decent Cuban cigar (the beginning is narrow and getting really spread towards the end). Also, the qq-plot follows S-shape, thus the residuals are not normally distributed. Is it an appropriate action to take to square root my skin conductance variable? An how does the interpretation change after transforming? Are my results now "more valid"? After the square root transformation, the residuals look quite alright. See the pictures (residuals after the transformation). Cheers!
[image: heterogenous residuals?][image: normal residuals?]

Comment: These are the residuals *after* transformation ?

Comment: Yes these are the residuals after transformation.